# Win2012R2 New-SelfSignedCertificate : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Provider'

Tags: azure, powershell, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, o365security-compliance

I'm fairly new to Azure and need to create an Azure application to authenticate against for a script which connects to Exchange Online (EXO3) and collects all Exchange Distribution Lists for a client.

The script works just fine on its own, however I need it to run as a scheduled task on a domain controller, so this requires Azure authentication. I created a basic self-signed cer file on the DC but because this doesn't have the property `Provider = 'Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider'`. I think the .cer file won't upload to Azure.

I get

> Failed to add certificate. Error detail: Upload a certificate (public key) with one of the following types : .cer, .pem, .crt

My cert is a .cer with password. From what I've read on this error and in [this MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/647007/how-to-fix-failed-to-add-certificate-error-detail) it seems that Azure needs certain properties including a 'Provider', and this provider from what I understand should be 'Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider'.

When I run the script below on my W2012R2 domain controller powershell doesn't understand the 'Provider' part and throws the error in the subject:

```
$automationAccount = 'GetDistributionLists'   
$certExpiryMonths = 24  
$certPfxPassword = 'blahblah'  
$certExportPath = 'C:\'  
$resourceGroup = 'Name of Azure App'  
$location = "UK"  
  
$certPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $certPfxPassword -AsPlainText -Force  
  
#Generate SSL certificate  
Write-Host "Generate self signed certificate for - $automationAccount"  
$selfSignedCertSplat = @{  
    DnsName = $automationAccount  
    Subject = $automationAccount  
    CertStoreLocation = 'cert:\CurrentUser\My'   
    KeyExportPolicy = 'Exportable'  
    Provider = 'Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider'  
    NotAfter = (Get-Date).AddMonths($certExpiryMonths)   
    HashAlgorithm = 'SHA256'  
}  
$selfSignedCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate @selfSignedCertSplat  
  
#Export SSL certificate to file  
Write-Host "Export self signed certificate to folder - $certExportPath"  
$certThumbPrint = 'cert:\CurrentUser\My\' + $selfSignedCert.Thumbprint  
Export-Certificate -Cert $certThumbPrint -FilePath "$certExportPath\$automationAccount.cer" -Type CERT | Write-Verbose
```

I get this error:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Provider'.
At \\dfs\users\userfolders\username\Desktop\GetDistributionGroupCertAzure.ps1:22 char:45
+ $selfSignedCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate @selfSignedCertSplat
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-SelfSignedCertificate], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.NewSelfSignedCertificateCommand
```

Does anyone know how to get round this? I need to create the cert on the DC (I think, as this is where the scheduled tasks is running from - but I could be wrong about this..) but it seems like some kind of Powershell version/module limitation to me which is stopping this from working.

Can anyone help shed some light on how I might get this working? Can I create it elsewhere and then just import it on the DC?

```
Powershell version:

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                                                         
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1029                                                                                                                                
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                       
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                       
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1029                                                                                                                               
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                               
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                           
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                           
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I've figured it out!

Simply, I had to create the cert locally with the higher OS/Powershell version I had on my local machine, then export to the DC and Azure...

Doh.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).